# Abrir registro específico en RadGrid luego de un evento de otro control

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2013, telerik

Estoy trabajando en `.Net` con `Telerik`, y en una página hay un control `RadTabStrip`:

[image: RadTabStrip]

En la pestaña `Indicadores` tengo lo siguiente:

[image: Indicadores]

Y en la pestaña `Estados` tengo el siguiente `RadGrid`:

[image: Estados]

Lo que debo hacer es que en la pestaña `Indicadores` al darle clic en el círculo verde (que es un hyperlink):

[image: Circulo Verde]

Esa acción me lleve a la pestaña `Estados` y me abra un registro específico del `RadGrid`, de esta manera:

[image: Abri registro]

Ya tengo el código que a partir del hypervinculo me pase a la pestaña `Estados` lo que no sé como hacer, es abrir un registro especifico por programación `c#`. Si alguien sabe como hacerlo se lo agradezco mucho.

**Nota**: El `RadGrid` principal tiene otro `RadGrid` secundario incrustado en un `NestedViewTemplate`:

```
<telerik:RadGrid ID="RgrdSolicitudesEstado" RenderMode="Lightweight" runat="server" Skin="MetroTouch" AllowSorting="true" AutoGenerateColumns="false" Culture="es-ES" ShowFooter="true" OnSortCommand="RgrdSolicitudesEstado_SortCommand" OnItemCommand="RgrdSolicitudesEstado_ItemCommand">
<PagerStyle PageSizeControlType="None" />
<MasterTableView DataKeyNames="Estado" HeaderStyle-CssClass="bn-grid-header" ItemStyle-CssClass="bn-grid-item" AlternatingItemStyle-CssClass="bn-grid-item" FooterStyle-CssClass="bn-grid-footer">
    <Columns>
        <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Estado" HeaderText="Estado" UniqueName="Estado" FooterText="Total General" ItemStyle-CssClass="bn-alineacion-justificada"></telerik:GridBoundColumn>
        <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Cantidad" HeaderText="Cantidad" UniqueName="Cantidad" Aggregate="Sum" FooterAggregateFormatString="{0:0}"></telerik:GridBoundColumn>
    </Columns>
    <NestedViewTemplate>
        <div class="bn-contenido-detalle-grid">
            <telerik:RadGrid ID="RgrdSolicitudesEstadoDetalle" RenderMode="Lightweight" runat="server" Skin="MetroTouch" AllowSorting="true" AutoGenerateColumns="false" Culture="es-ES"
            AllowPaging="true" PageSize="5" OnPageIndexChanged="RgrdSolicitudesEstadoDetalle_PageIndexChanged" OnSortCommand="RgrdSolicitudesEstadoDetalle_SortCommand">
            <PagerStyle PageSizeControlType="None" />
                <MasterTableView HeaderStyle-CssClass="bn-grid-header" ItemStyle-CssClass="bn-grid-item" AlternatingItemStyle-CssClass="bn-grid-item">
                    <Columns>
                        <telerik:GridTemplateColumn HeaderText="Número" UniqueName="Numero">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:LinkButton ID="LnkBtnNumero" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Numero") %>' ToolTip="Ver gestión de cambio" CssClass="bn-link" PostBackUrl='<%# "~/TI/Infraestructura/BusquedaCambios.aspx?req=" + Eval("Numero")%>'></asp:LinkButton>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
                        <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Titulo" HeaderText="Título" UniqueName="Titulo"></telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                        <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Fecha" HeaderText="Fecha Ingreso" UniqueName="Fecha" DataFormatString="{0:d}"></telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                        <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Sistema" HeaderText="Sistema" UniqueName="Sistema"></telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                        <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="TipoCriticidad" HeaderText="Criticidad" UniqueName="TipoCriticidad"></telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                        <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="CategoriaCambio" HeaderText="Categoría Cambio" UniqueName="CategoriaCambio"></telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                        <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Dias" HeaderText="Días" UniqueName="Dias"></telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                    </Columns>
                </MasterTableView>
            </telerik:RadGrid>
        </div>
    </NestedViewTemplate>
</MasterTableView>
</telerik:RadGrid>
```